# How to call a variable FROM another method INSIDE the main the method to perform a math calculation

Tags: java, math, methods, count

Maybe I'm just stupid (probably) but I have been struggling with this for LITERALLY the past five hours and I really can't figure it out. Nothing on this site / google seems to help me; everyone wants to know how to call a method that's defined in the main method in another method, but I am trying to do it the other way around. I am new to java, but I am aware that you can't directly call a variable from a method into another method. However, I have tried so many different iterations of trying to get the values and NOTHING is compiling and I get the same errors over and over again: "error: cannot find symbol" for all of my variables.

All I am trying to do is read a text file and print out what percentage of the words are of x length up to 13 and say how many of those words are in the document so like "Proportion of 1- letter words: .7% (2 words)" is printed out all the way to "Proportion of 13- letter words: 80.7% (7000 words)" (this is how the output is supposed to look, I know it's not pretty).

Anyway please help me because I am stuck and tearing my hair out.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileReader
{
public static void main (String [] args)throws FileNotFoundException
{

    WordCount();
    WordLengthCount();

    File file = new File("RomeoAndJuliet.txt");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));

    System.out.println("Proportion of 1-letter words: " + count1/count + "% (" + count1 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 2-letter words: " + count2/count + "% (" + count2 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 3-letter words: " + count3/count + "% (" + count3 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 4-letter words: " + count4/count + "% (" + count4 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 5-letter words: " + count5/count + "% (" + count5 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 6-letter words: " + count6/count + "% (" + count6 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 7-letter words: " + count7/count + "% (" + count7 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 8-letter words: " + count8/count + "% (" + count8 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 9-letter words: " + count9/count + "% (" + count9 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 10-letter words: " + count10/count + "% (" + count10 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 11-letter words: " + count11/count + "% (" + count11 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 12-letter words: " + count12/count + "% (" + count12 + " words)");
    System.out.println("Proportion of 13-letter words: " + count13/count + "% (" + count13 + " words)");
}


public static int WordCount(int n)throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File("RomeoAndJuliet.txt");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    int countABC=0;
    while(keyboard.hasNext())
    {
        keyboard.next();
        countABC++;
    }
    return countABC;
}

public static int WordLengthCount(int n) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File("RomeoAndJuliet.txt");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));

    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int count4 = 0;
    int count5 = 0;
    int count6 = 0;
    int count7 = 0;
    int count8 = 0;
    int count9 = 0;
    int count10 = 0;
    int count11 = 0;
    int count12 = 0;
    int count13 = 0;

    int blob = 0; // so that if statement runs

    while(keyboard.hasNext())
    {
        if (keyboard.next().length() == 1)
        {
            count1++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count1;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 2)
        {
            count2++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count2;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 3)
        {
            count3++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count3;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 4)
        {
            count4++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count4;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 5)
        {
            count5++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count5;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 6)
        {
            count6++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count6;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 7)
        {
            count7++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count7;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 8)
        {
            count8++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count8;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 9)
        {
            count9++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count9;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 10)
        {
            count10++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count10;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 11)
        {
            count11++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count11;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 12)
        {
            count12++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count12;
        }
        else if (keyboard.next().length() == 13)
        {
            count13++;
            keyboard.next();
            return count13;
        }
    }   return blob;
}
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Your first (among loads) of problem is you are not passing a parameter in your call to `WordCount()`.  Also, define `count1` and others outside a method.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code was not designed and written in the right way. Do you have specific algorithm? do you know the principles of structural programming? I recommend you to search for `count words in text file java` in Google. goodluck

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad because your algorithmcan't work this way. Please reconsider your algortihm - what happens if the word has more than `13`  chars? I would use a dictionary, wordlengtjh as key, instance count as value.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable static and call it from the main method

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code, but the biggest one is that you are returning the count when you find a word that has a specific Length.

You may want to create a class (say Document) that has the attributes you listed as variables in WordLengthCount (int count1, int count2, etc). Since attributes should most often be private, I would suggest doing an increment count method.

Finally, your WordLengthCount, can call the increment count method for the right word type, and return the object that you have created.

Moreover, instead of creating 13 variables, I would recommend using an array instead

```
int[] wordCount= new int[13];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access local variables of one function in some other function. This is not possible. As the name suggests, local variables are local to the block or function in which they are declared. If you want to globally access these variables, make them class-level variables, i.e. declare them inside the class body but outside of any other function. Also, if you want to access them from static methods without creating object of the class, make these variables static.